# RubyOnRails Exctract informations from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, request

What kind of request to database do I need to send to get a table of this nature:

--Drug's name-----Saller 1-----Saller 2-----Saller 3

--drug 1 ------------price 1-------price 2 ------price 3

--drug 2-------------price 4-------price 5-------price  6

There are next models:
drug table have names of drugs

```
class Drug < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :drug_pharmacies     
  has_many :pharmacies, through: :drug_pharmacies 
end
```

Pharmacy table have names of pharmacies

```
class Pharmacy < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :drug_pharmacies
    has_many :drugs, through: :drug_pharmacies
end
```

DrugPharmacies table have Drug_id, Pharmacy_id, price

```
class DrugPharmacy < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :drug
    belongs_to :pharmacy
end
```

In controller list of pharmacies (sellers) I have formed such a request (the logic in finding competitors that are located next to the main pharmacy by geolocation)

```
pharmacy= Pharmacy.find(params[:id])
longitude = pharmacy.x
latitude = pharmacy.y
@competitors = Pharmacy.where(x: (longitude-0.005..longitude+0.005), y: (latitude-0.005..latitude+0.005))
```

In the same controller, I send information about medicines

```
@drugs = Drug.all.sort_by &:name
```

And with such requests, I have to go into the database on view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>names</th> 
    <% @competitors.each do |apteka| %>        #filling the table with sellers
      <th><%= apteka.name %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
                              #filling the table body with drugs and prices from competitors
  <% @drugs.each do |drug| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= drug.name %></td>
      <% @competitors.length.times do |i| %>    #The problem in the presentation here is I suppose
        <td> <%= drug.drug_pharmacies.find_by_pharmacy_id(@competitors[i].id).price %> 
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was :

```
pharmacy= Pharmacy.find(params[:id])
longitude, latitude = pharmacy.x, pharmacy.y
@competitors = Pharmacy.where(x: (longitude-0.005..longitude+0.005),
                              y: (latitude-0.005..latitude+0.005))
```

In @competitors we found our rivals on square. And then use func includes:

```
@drugs = Drug
            .includes(:drug_pharmacies)
            .where(drug_pharmacies: {pharmacy_id: @competitors.ids})
```

This collect all name of drugs with prices for all your competitors.